# C++ Using an overriden method after passing as superclass

Tags: c++, function, methods, virtual, superclass

If I have a C++ function/method, for example:

```
getSound(Animal a){
  a.printSound();
}
```

and then pass it a `Dog` object that extends the class `Animal` but overrides Animal's `printSound()` method, is there a way of using Dog's `printSound()` within `getSound()`?

I have tried making `printSound()` in the `Animal` class definition virtual, but I am still getting the output of the original `printSound()`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, polymorphism dictates, that it calls the derived function class, if present...however, have you tried passing the pointer to the object in question? Because the way I see it, you pass a copy, which could well lead to a 'real' conversion to 'Animal'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making `printSound` virtual was correct. Change the signature of `getSound` to take a `Animal&` or `const Animal&`. By taking an `Animal` by value you are constructing a new `Animal` from your `Dog`, and that's just an `Animal`, not a `Dog`.

Answer (score 6):

It is because of [object-slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing), as you accept the argument by value.

Accept it by reference as:

```
void getSound(Animal & a); //now reference
```

If `Animal::printSound()` doesn't change the state of the object, then make it `const` member function (if it isn't const already), and then accept the argument by `const` reference as:

```
void getSound(Animal const & a); //now const reference
```

Answer (score 5):

When you call `getSound`, you are passing the `Animal` by value. This means that a copy of the `Dog` is made by calling the `Animal`'s copy constructor. The `Animal`'s copy constructor constructs an `Animal`, not a `Dog`. You probably want pass by reference:

```
getSound(Animal& a){
  a.printSound();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You've basically done everything right, except for one thing.

Either pass the Animal object by reference

```
getSound(Animal &a);
```

Or provide a pointer to the object in question.

```
getSound(Animal *a) {
    a->printSound();  //Mind the -> in this case.
}
```

To call this function, you'd go about like this:

```
Dog D;
getSound(&D);    //Passes a pointer to the function.
```

Otherwise, you'll construct a new object of type 'Animal', instead of really 'passing' a Dog.

Actually, you're best off with the pointer solution, otherwise you'll run into problems when passing a derived object, since it will expect an object of type `Animal` and will not settle for anything else.